# Computer worms, propagation and exploiting vulnerabilities

Tags: network, malware, virus, antivirus

I am doing research on computer worms. I have been through several sites and a few caught my attention. I have learned that worms propagate through email, there are types such as XSS worm and most of them are written in scripting languages and some through c and c++ which aren't scripting languages.

How is a worm made in c and c++ and is able to travel through the internet? Does it use some sort of protocol? I am not sure where to begin and how worms target vulnerabilities. I am looking for a small explanation and probably some sort of code that shows it exploiting a vulnerability. These are the sites I have visited and read:

- http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~jain/cse571-09/ftp/worms/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_worm

Comment: http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/1361/why-not-answering-questions-from-homeworks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good example of a self-propagating worm which targeted a specific vulnerability was [Sasser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasser_worm) which exploited a vulnerability in Windows to propagate.

The author of the Sasser worm was monitoring the updates Microsoft releases for Windows. [One of them](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms04-011) was fixing something Microsoft referred to as a "Critical Remote Code Execution Vulnerability", which for a malware author reads "$$$ JACKPOT! $$$". By downloading and examining the update he found out how exactly the bug worked.

Every Windows installation has a background program called "Local Security Authority Subsystem Service" (lsass.exe) which starts with the system and listens to port 445. Any other system on the internet can connect to this service. However, they can not do anything unless they send the correct login credentials, so this service is usually harmless. But Microsoft found and fixed a bug in this program: When you send a specifically crafted message to it, a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) will happen and parts of this message will be executed as a program.

So the author wrote a program which (grossly oversimplified):

1. connects to random IP addresses, port 445
2. sends the malicious message including its own code

When the system didn't install the update yet, it would also execute this program which would then do the same thing there.

This is basically how all internet worms work. The author finds a vulnerability which allows to execute arbitrary code. They write a program which automatically searches for vulnerable systems and then uses the vulnerability to smuggle a copy of itself onto the system and execute it.

What do we learn from this? Install any released updates fast, because the moment a software vendor releases an update, the vulnerability is known and black hats will start writing malware which exploits it. You must install the patch before they are finished!

Comment: I love this explanation, could you please refer me to sites that show sample code of how worms are written and in what language they're written because I have no idea how applications can connect to random IPs, what happens exactly, if you could explain and refer me to links. I am currently reading on the buffer overflow

Comment: @Hawk Typically a low-level language such as assembly or C is used to develop these worms; this allows the programmer to have a greater control of operating system interactions (one of the main attack vectors malware use). This answer may be of some use in understanding the [programming languages chosen to develop malware](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/55965/25922).

Comment: thank you @VilhelmGray, that was rather helpful, I have no experience with machine code so it is totally out of the question hehe